# How to put the value of <Input type=date/> to var outside the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Im Trying to put the Value of dtpFrom to var FDate

I know my Javascript is wrong. I provided them so that you may know what I need to do.

```html
  var FDate = "";
    var TDate = "";
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("FDate").value = document.getElementById("dtpFrom").value;
            document.getElementById("TDate").value = document.getElementById("dtpTo").value;
         
        }
    </script>

    <p>
        <strong><b>Find by MAWB: @Html.TextBox("searchstring")</b></strong>
        <strong><b>From: @Html.TextBox("fromDate", FDate)</b></strong>
        <strong><b>To: @Html.TextBox("toDate", TDate)</b></strong>
        <input type="Date" id="dtpFrom" onchange="myFunction()" />
        <input type="Date" id="dtpTo" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
```

Comment: This make no sense. Either you are using something more than HTML or this is completely invalid code. Where does `@Html.TextBox("searchstring")` come from?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/0zfjy75r/1/

```
  var FDate = "<span id="FDate"></span>";
  var TDate = "<span id="TDate"></span>";
<script>
  function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("FDate").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dtpFrom").value;
        document.getElementById("TDate").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dtpTo").value;
  }
</script>

<p>
    <strong><b>Find by MAWB: @Html.TextBox("searchstring")</b></strong>
    <strong><b>From: @Html.TextBox("fromDate", FDate)</b></strong>
    <strong><b>To: @Html.TextBox("toDate", TDate)</b></strong><br>

    <input type="Date" id="dtpFrom" onchange="myFunction()" />
    <input type="Date" id="dtpTo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
```

Comment: Hi 004123 Thank you for your response, Since you put the var inside the script. The variable "FDate & TDate" does not exist anymore inside the Html.Textbox.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are looking for however I think that I have updated my answer to suit your needs. If not can you please explain better what you are looking for.